# Flush the toilet and I hear gurgling in my shower

Tags: shower

When I flush the toilet the shower gurgles. Could this be because the shower hasn't been used in about 2 years? Also I hear it when I flush my toilet at the other end of the house in the same shower.

Comment: You trap is empty due to evaporation, you should run water in there occasionally. I am surprised you did not experience unpleasant odors because the water seal in the trap prevents sewer gases from entering your home.

Answer (score 1):

it means that your shower is plumbed up with an absent vent line or a vent that is blocked or plugged.  if it just showed up recently, i would look for an ice cap on a roof vent pipe.  if its an ongoing thing, then i would suspect an absent vent pipe.  you can quick fix it with a rubber drain cover.

[http://www.amazon.com/Do-it-Rubber-Sink-Stopper/dp/B000DZD3QA/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1457233324&sr=1-1&keywords=rubber+drain+cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000DZD3QA)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? I read other sites and it said that if the shower hasn't been used in a long time the water in the trap has evaporated and that could cause this. We poured a couple cups of water down the drain and flushed both toliets and we didn't hear the noise. This "sound" just started about 1 month or so ago.

Comment: if its the shower "gurgling" then you are getting suction  on the drain line downstream of the shower trap.  ergo there is an absent or blocked vent pipe, or an inadequately sized vent pipe (unlikely).  if you are hearing the toilet "gurgling" through the empty trap, and it stops when you fill the trap with water, then i don't understand why you asked the question.  it sounds like you already solved it.